# D3 data not updating

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I'm trying to learn some of the basic concepts of d3, but i'm getting stuck when it comes to updating data thats already binded to my html elements.

I created a js fiddle to show case the issue [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xthom001/maxqoagt/1/)

What I'm trying to do is create a bar that has a full width of about 860px that has several other bars over it. Those other bars will have a width thats a percentage of the bars total width.

[image: Bar Thats Generated]

So this bar is generated from the data that I pass into the first d3 join.
I want to update this data with a new bar of a different size but everytime I try and add a new item the graph shrinks to showing only the new bar.

[image]

I am not using svg to render out my bar, i'm still learning the basics, but here is the code:

### D3

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
.domain( [ 0, d3.max( percents, function ( d ) {
    return d.percent
} ) ] )
.range( [ 0, chartRange ] );

chart.selectAll( 'div' ) // Creates an empty selection of divs
.data( percents, function ( d, i ) {
    // Joins the specified array of data with the current selection
    return d.percent;
} )
.enter().append( 'div' )
.style( 'width', function ( d ) {
    return x( d.percent ) + 'px';
} )
.style( {
    'height': '20px'
} )
.style( 'z-index', function ( d, i ) {
    return percents.length - i;
} )
.style( {
    'border-right': '2px dotted #00D0BC'
} )
.style( {
    'text-align': 'right'
} )
.append( 'p' )
.text( function ( d ) {
    return d.num * 10;
} );
```

### Data

```
var percents = [
{
    num: 0,
    percent: 0,
    changed: false
},
{
    num: 30,
    percent: 0,
    changed: false
},
{
    num: 50,
    percent: 0,
    changed: false
},
{
    num: 70,
    percent: 0,
    changed: false
},
{
    num: 90,
    percent: 0,
    changed: false
},
{
    num: 100,
    percent: 0,
    changed: false
}
];
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the problem yet. The fiddle shows a complete bar from 0 to 1000. What should the actual result look like? Should all the bars add up to 100% and be next to each other filling up the original bar or should each bar overlap each time? For example: your first bar now shows 389, suppose the following update is 500, you would no longer see the 389 bar (which would mean that you only want to show 1 percentage at a time?)

Comment: So theirs one bar that adds all the way up to 100 percent. Every other bar has the css attribute for border-right: 2px dashed blue, which explains why you dont see the other bars. Now the z-index is calculated backwards so the smallest bars would have the highest z index and vice versus for the largest. My issue is that  when i try and add a new object into my array I'm unable to update the bars @ocket-san

Answer (score 2):

You have to manually call D3 again and tell it to re-render your data. This is done by re-binding the data again.

So encapsulate your "drawing" functionality into a function like so:

```
function renderData(percents) {
    chart.selectAll('div') // Creates an empty selection of divs
        .data(percents, function (d, i) {
            // Joins the specified array of data with the current selection
            return d.percent;
        })
        .enter().append('div')
        .style('width', function (d) {
            return x(d.percent) + 'px';
        })
        .style({
            'height': '20px'
        })
        .style('z-index', function (d, i) {
            return percents.length - i;
        })
        .style({
            'border-right': '2px dotted #00D0BC'
        })
        .style({
            'text-align': 'right'
        })
        .append('p')
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.num * 10;
        });
}
```

And everytime you change your data, just call `renderData(percents)` again.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, but when I do an inspection of the the web console it shows that new element I added being appended to the list of bars in the Dom. Why is it not rendering in order like it did before?

Comment: well, now that I somewhat think to understand what you really want, I did notice something in your fiddle: In your css, you have a rule that says: #bar-chart div:last-child and in that css, you give the bars the blue color. According to your css, the other bars ( #bar-chart div ) dont have a background color. When y ou render a new bar, it becomes the last child and it gets the blue color, while the other bars will no longer have any background color.